# Write a program that takes a user input string and outputs every second word

Tags: python, string, output, cpu-word

Please enter a sentence: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Output: The brown jumps the dog

I've been doing some learning in strings in python, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to write a program that will remove the 2nd letter of every sentence.

```
word=(input ("enter setence"))

del word[::2]

print(word[char], 
end="")

Print("\n")
```

This was my closest attempt. At least I was able to write the sentence on the command prompt but was unable to get the required output.

Comment: And what's your question? Or you think somebody will do your homework?

Comment: I did give this problem a try but I was unable to get the solution, I researched strings in python but I was still not able to get an answer. So I just needed some help from others on what I did wrong and learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

```
string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
even_words = string.split(' ')[::2]
```

You split the original string using spaces, then you take every other word from it with the [::2] splice.

Comment: See Also: [Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

`" ".join(c for c in word.split(" ")[::2])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sentenceInput=(input ("Please enter sentence: "))

# Function for deleting every 2nd word
def wordDelete(sentence):

    # Splitting sentence into pieces by thinking they're seperated by space.
    # Comma and other signs are kept.
    sentenceList = sentence.split(" ")

    # Checking if sentence contains more than 1 word seperated and only then remove the word
    if len(sentenceList) > 1:
        sentenceList.remove(sentenceList[1])

    # If not raise the exception
    else:
        print("Entered sentence does not contain two words.")
        raise Exception

    # Re-joining sentence
    droppedSentence = ' '.join(sentenceList)

    # Returning the result
    return droppedSentence

wordDelete(sentenceInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that.

`sentence = input("enter sentence: ")
words = sentence.split(' ')
print(words[::2])`

Comment: Did _you_ try it?